# Displaying array from javascript in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array i make in javascript with 2 columns id and quantity

```
items.push({
            id : id,
            quantity: quantity
        })
```

I then use stringify to make it into a jsonstring as shown

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(items);
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "order_process.php",
            data: {data : jsonString}, 
            cache: false,

            success: function(){
            
                window.location.href = "order_confirmation.php";
                

            
            }
});
```

I then post it to php and use json_decode to turn it into a php array. as shown

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = json_decode( $_POST['data'] );
```

The problem is when i use the print_r() function in php, this is the output I get

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 12 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 13 [quantity] => 1 ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 10 [quantity] => 1 ) 
)
```

The output I want is as shown below, but I don't know how to format this so I get it as shown

| ID | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 |
| 13 | 2 |

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: @MonoConman What is “the problem”? What exactly are you trying that results in no output?

Comment: `print_r()` is for debugging, it's not for formatting information for end users.

Comment: `foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) { // print table row from $item }`

Comment: You're redirecting to `order_confirmation.php`, so you shouldn't see the output of the `order_process.php` script at all.

Comment: Sorry it goes to order_process where it stores it as a session variable, then to order_confirmation to display it

Answer (score 0):

Use `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode()` to get an array instead of an object. Then loop to create your table:

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = json_decode( $_POST['data'], true );
echo '<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Quantity</th></tr>';
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$item['id'].'</td><td>'.$item['quantity'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Why do you need an array instead of object? You can do the same thing with `$item->id` and `$item->quantity`

Comment: You don't but I think it's confusing the op.

Comment: So clear up his confusion by showing how to access object properties!

Comment: I just noticed that his `success` function redirects, so the output of the AJAX script isn't even displayed.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing in JS is not creating the associative array in the same sense as it is in PHP.

You're actually doing exactly what you get when you JSON decode: You push (append to array) an object (curly braces) with two properties.

What you could do to output array in PHP is either:

- use what you have and use objects for iteration in PHP
- pass two regular JS arrays - one with IDs and one with quantities

In any way you would need to know how to wrap the data with HTML so you actually can display the table.